# React Hooks - useCallback performance

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Im writing my product in React Hooks and yes, Im just new to it.

Today I have math about useCallback performance.This makes me consider a lot to use useCallback or not use.

Let have a look. As we know, useCallback is use for better performance.

```
function MainScreen() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [pwd, setPwd] = useState(""):

  const onAuthenticate = useCallback(() => {
    MyApi.authenticate(email, pwd);
  }, [email, pwd]);

  return <div>
    <MyCustomButton onPress={onAuthenticate}>LOGIN</MyCustomButton>
  </div>;
}
```

In the example above, let's assume there are two inputs of email and password then `MyCustomButton` will be rendered all the times email or password changes. I tried to use `useCallback` to reduce number times of render but for me, it is not good enough.

Later, I figured out a way, take out email and pwd in dependencies and use `useRef` to hold value of email and password.

```
function MainScreen() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [pwd, setPwd] = useState(""):

  const emailRef = useRef(email);
  const pwdRef = useRef(pwd);

  const onAuthenticate = useCallback(() => {
    MyApi.authenticate(emailRef.current, pwdRef.current);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    emailRef.current = email;
    pwdRef.current = pwd;
  }, [email, pwd]);

  return <div>
    <MyCustomButton onPress={onAuthenticate}>LOGIN</MyCustomButton>
  </div>;
}
```

With this approach, it stops rendering in `MyCustomButton` every time email or password changes.

Is it actually better in performance and cost? What do you think guys?

Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

The issue that I am seeing with your code is not with `useCallback` - it's with `useState`.

A rule of thumb in react (whether you use hooks or not) is that the state has a direct impact on what is being displayed. If you modify the state, it means that the component should be re-rendered.

This rationale is what makes your component re-render when using useState. React assumes that `email` and `password` are things that change how your component should look like, therefore, it is being rerendered whenever you change one of their values.

If you don't actually use `email` and `pwd` in `MyCustomButton`, then using `useRef` instead of `useState` makes more sense.

However, the way you are using it in your second code sample doesn't make a lot of sense: You are combining `useState` and `useRef` so that when `email` changes (which will be the case when you use `setEmail`, then you update the ref with the same value. The only benefit that you get out of it is that onAuthenticate is not reconstructed every time.

It would be more beneficial to skip `useState` entirely, but from the code you posted, it is difficult to actually propose a different solution, as it is not clear how/when `email` and `pwd` are actually set.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only performing an API call, I recommend **not to use** `useCallback()`. Make it a normal function instead.

You could be doing a premature optimization. You should only do performance optimization, if you are performing heavy computations on your app and you need to memoize your values.

An in-depth comparison of a normal function vs a function that uses `useCallback()` can be seen from [here.](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback)

Answer (score 0):

in this case, I would like use React.memo instead of useCallback.
use React.memo to make sure this component will not call render cased by parent,
once component call render, email or pwd have changed, so useCallback is unnecessary

```
function MainScreen() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [pwd, setPwd] = useState(""):

  const onAuthenticate = () => {
    MyApi.authenticate(email, pwd);
  };

  return <div>
    <MyCustomButton onPress={onAuthenticate}>LOGIN</MyCustomButton>
  </div>;
}
export default React.memo(MainScreen)
```